# Из XML в Таблицу

Tags: sql, sql-server, xquery

**Задача:** Вывести атрибут ProductID и элементы Price и Autors для каждого продукта в отдельную таблицу.

**Исходный код:**

```
DECLARE @xmlDocument XML
SET @xmlDocument =
N'<Root>
<Order><Items>
     <Product ProductID="1" ProductName="Book1" ProductCategory="A">
     <Price val="RUB" PValue="300"/>
     <Autors lang="русский">
<Autor>Автор1</Autor><Autor>Автор2</Autor></Autors><Features><Description>ОписаниетовараBook1</Description><Garant>3 года</Garant></Features></Product>
     <Product ProductID="2" ProductName="Book2" ProductCategory="F">
     <Price val="DOL" PValue="50"/>
     <Autors lang="английский">
<Autor>Autor1</Autor><Autor>Autor1</Autor></Autors><Features> <Description>Описание товара Book2</Description><Garant>1 год</Garant></Features></Product>
     <Product ProductID="3" ProductName="Book3" ProductCategory="A">
     <Price val="RUB" PValue="700"/>
     <Autors lang="русский">
<Autor>Автор 3</Autor><Autor>Автор 4</Autor></Autors><Features><Description>ОписаниетовараBook3</Description><Garant>2 года</Garant></Features></Product>
</Items></Order>

<Order><Items>
     <Product ProductID="4" ProductName="Book4" ProductCategory="A">
     <Price val="RUB" PValue="900"/>
     <Autors lang="русский">
<Autor>Автор 5</Autor></Autors><Features><Garant>3 года</Garant</Features</Product>
</Items></Order>
</Root>'
```

**Необходимый результат:**
1   300    русский
2   500    английский
3   700    русский
4   900    русский

**Мой код, не давший ожидаемого результата:**

```
SELECT xmlDocument.n.value('@ProductID', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [ProductId],
       xmlDocument.n.value('@PValue','INT') AS [Price],
       xmlDocument.n.value('@lang','INT') AS [Autors]

FROM @xmlDocument.nodes('Root/Order/Items/Product') xmlDocument (n)
```

**Фактический результат**
[image: Результат моего кода]

***Прошу помочь!***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примечание: в представленном xml не хватает двух закрывающих угловых скобок.

Запрос должен выглядеть так:

```
SELECT xmlDocument.n.value('@ProductID', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [ProductId],
       xmlDocument.n.value('Price[1]/@PValue', 'INT') AS [Price],
       xmlDocument.n.value('Autors[1]/@lang', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [Autors]

FROM @xmlDocument.nodes('Root/Order/Items/Product') xmlDocument (n)
```

Нужно добавить названия узлов: `Price` и `Autors`, а также изменить тип последнего значения.

Comment: Спасибо, выручил.  =))